# Gnome-terminal slow start for first instance on arch

Tags: gnome-terminal, awesome

I am using the Awesome window manager with Arch, kernel 6.5.5.

When I start gnome-terminal for the first time and every other time where I don't already have an instance of gnome-terminal running, it takes several seconds (~20 seconds).

I have tried using the gnome window manager as it was suggested in [this similar issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/19839/586937)

and it does fix the issue, but I don't want to use another window manager.

I am very interested in how to investigate and solve this problem, but I am unsure of what to look for.

`journalctl --user -r` :

```
Oct 07 07:59:25 arch-pc xdg-desktop-por[6096]: Failed to create settings proxy: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.impl.portal.desktop.gnome: Timeout was reached
Oct 07 07:59:00 arch-pc systemd[1673]: Started VTE child process 6212 launched by gnome-terminal-server process 6091.
Oct 07 07:58:35 arch-pc systemd[1673]: xdg-desktop-portal-gnome.service: Job xdg-desktop-portal-gnome.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Oct 07 07:58:35 arch-pc systemd[1673]: Dependency failed for Portal service (GNOME implementation).
Oct 07 07:58:35 arch-pc systemd[1673]: Current graphical user session is inactive.
Oct 07 07:58:35 arch-pc dbus-daemon[1699]: [session uid=1000 pid=1699] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.impl.portal.desktop.gnome' unit='xdg-desktop-portal-gnome.service>
Oct 07 07:58:35 arch-pc systemd[1673]: Starting Portal service...
Oct 07 07:58:35 arch-pc dbus-daemon[1699]: [session uid=1000 pid=1699] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.portal.Desktop' unit='xdg-desktop-portal.service' requested by ':>
Oct 07 07:58:35 arch-pc systemd[1673]: Started GNOME Terminal Server.
Oct 07 07:58:35 arch-pc dbus-daemon[1699]: [session uid=1000 pid=1699] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Terminal'
Oct 07 07:58:35 arch-pc systemd[1673]: Starting GNOME Terminal Server...
Oct 07 07:58:35 arch-pc dbus-daemon[1699]: [session uid=1000 pid=1699] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.Terminal' unit='gnome-terminal-server.service' requested by ':1.41' (ui>
Oct 07 07:54:43 arch-pc sudo[5217]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

Stating that `xdg-desktop-portal-gnome.service` is having trouble starting.

A recent update fixed this issue on my pc.
the packages below where all updated.

```
xdg-desktop-portal-1.18.0-2
xdg-desktop-portal-gnome-44.2-2  
xdg-desktop-portal-gtk-1.14.1-3
```

Just to be clear, I did not manage to find `xdg-desktop-portal-gnome.service` with systemctl on my pc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what's exactly wrong, but you can probably check the journal for log of the `gnome-terminal-server.service` **user** service to see if it actually reported anything:

```
journalctl --user-unit gnome-terminal-server.service
```

The systemd service is started via dbus through its "companion" dbus service file. There will be only one server instance at a time and the server will exit whenever all the windows/tabs have been closed. So what you are experiencing indicates that it occurs every time during the starting up of the server. It could be the "channel" (dbus) that has problem. It could also be just a problem of the server process itself.

You may also want to just check `journalctl -e` and `journalctl --user -e` after the problem occured in case it is something else that is stalling the startup.

For the record, it's not expected to be slow even if you are not in a GNOME session and/or not using GDM to start your window manager. In my experience it  still starts faster than the python-based terminator anyway in normal circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, `gnome-terminal` needs to load various Gnome libraries to run. Since you are not running Gnome, these haven't been loaded so will need to be loaded the first time a Gnome program is launched. You might be able to fix this by running some gnome thing automatically on login, but really, I would suggest you just use a different terminal emulator instead.

Personally, I am very fond of [`terminator`](https://gnome-terminator.org/). However, that might also have gnome stuff included. It loads very quickly on my Arch system, but I use Cinnamon, which is based on Gnome and might be loading some Gnome stuff. Still, try `terminator` and see if it is faster, it really is a great terminal.

If that doesn't work, just go for any non-Gnome terminal emulator. [xfce4-terminal] should be very fast and non-Gnome. So is `xterm`, of course, but that's a bit basic for modern usage. Have a look at [the list Wikipedia has](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_terminal_emulators), try a few and see if you can find one you like that is fast.

Comment: Yes this problem probably occurred after removing or replacing a service using Gnome libraries. thank you for the help !

Comment: No offense but the theory here really doesn't make much sense. Not only that gnome-terminal isn't really that "coupled" to gnome-session or so, one hardly need 5 seconds to start a full blown GNOME DE with GDM included anyway, let alone "library loading" (assuming if you are talking about usual linkage that are everywhere GNOME or non-GNOME; KDE stuff often have way more linkage btw). I'd say the problem might have something to do with a half-broken dbus setup or so. As per the description, it seems that the time is introduced by the starting of a server instance though.

Comment: @TomYan no offense taken, this is just a wild guess! However, my guess is that the OP is not using GDM and the fact that this only happens the first time gnome-terminal is loaded _and_ does not happen when using Gnome as DE, does suggest that something needs to be loaded somewhere by something. If it were a dbus issue, wouldn't the same thing occur when running Gnome as well? As for KDE, of course it has more, but I don't really see why that's relevant.

Comment: @V42 You might want to check the system journal to see if there's any relevant error btw. Sounds like it's waiting/looking for something until a timeout is over.

Comment: @terdon the OP apparently noted that it occurs within gnome-session as well. Either way, I've been using gnome-terminal in i3 and it has never started slower than terminator (well python, so). And the reason why it occurs to the OP *every first time when there's no existing window* is because gnome-terminal has some sort of server-client design, and each server instance remains until all windows/tabs are gone.

Comment: Sounds like you should post an answer, @TomYan. And downvote mine (downvoting is important, it is how we can control quality). But no, the OP said that using Gnome fixes the issue, they just don't want to use Gnome.

Comment: @TomYan I fully agree with you. Having to load the libraries is most certainly not the cause of the problem (I suspect something around dbus / systemd activation, trying to connect to a subsystem that's not (or not properly) running, and waiting for a timeout, but unfortunately I'm not familiar with that area). And recommending to use a different terminal emulator doesn't fix the problem and doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @egmont then please downvote my answer! That's two of you now who think it is wrong and neither has downvoted. Downvoting is a very imprtant part of quality control here.